# Project version was not returned by info actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

There is spring boot application
I am  trying to create custom response for spring info actuator
as following . Relevant definitions from application.properties file are :

```
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info
management.info.defaults.enabled=false
management.info.env.enabled=true
info.build.version=@project.version@
```

In pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app-parent</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
    ....
</project>
```

But when accessing info actuator endpoint  :

```
http://{{myAppUrl}}/actuator/info
```

I got response (expected result - to get actual version , instead of "@project.version@")

```
{
    "build": {
        "version": "@project.version@"
    }
}
```

What can be missing in definitions ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your POM do any replacements of text or strings at assembly time?  Where's that in your POM definition?

Comment: not sure if you can read from pom at runtime because your pom will be project but your properties will be read during application bootup process so it may not work.

Comment: @prasannajoshi:  You wouldn't be able to; the conventional way is to do text replacements at build time.

Comment: Should @project.version@ be obtained from generated META_INF\build-info.properties ?